# Joomla .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting

Just trying to change my URL from http://bruteforce.tv/index.php/streams/shinigamily
to
http://bruteforce.tv/shinigamily

I activated the Rewrite Option in the admin panel and used the original joomla htaccess file and the url went to

```
http://bruteforce.tv/streams/shinigamily
```

At this point I wrote `RewriteRule ^streams/(.*)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R]` after the `# RewriteBase /`

Somehow it doesnt work. My webhost already edited his `httpd.conf` with

```
<Directory "/home/htdocs/webX/html">
AllowOverride All
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

But it didnt change anything either.

> Now, the hard way is much more advanced and requires you to do the
>   following:
>
> Modify Joomla’s SEF core files in order to remove the category name
>   from the URL. (Note: There are several files that need to be changed.)
>
> Ensure that the change you’ve done above is accommodated in your
>   .htaccess file.
>
> Ensure that you don’t break any functionality with this code change.

Blackquote of `http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-remove-the-category-name-from-the-url-in-joomla`

Now I feel sunk.

Here is my htacces file:

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.

Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
RewriteRule ^streams/(.*)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: I'm just looking for a little clarification here - if it's showing index.php - it doesn't sound like you have SEF URL's enabled in your Joomla installation.  Is that enabled?  Also, is Joomla installed in the root directory?  Or is 'streams' the name of the directory it's installed in and you're trying to get rid of it?  Different ways to it depending on how you answer those questions.

Comment: SEF URL is enabled. (But not during my Joomla isntallation. I changed my webspace a few days ago.) Yes Joomla is installed in the root directory. No /streams/ is just the name of the category. There is no existing direcotry called streams.

Comment: Have you got any idea?

Comment: Did that rewrite rule work on your previous webspace?

Comment: I only used it on my current webspace.

Comment: Did you try the other method listed in the link you put up there?  To simply create a Category Blog layout for the menu item?  Then the category name won't show in the URL.

Comment: Hm no I didnt try that. I dont feel like its a good solution. Maybe somethings in the original joomla file doesnt agree with my code.

Comment: Honestly my website worked fine before I even used a htaccess file. The only reason why I converted the already existing htaccess.txt to .htaccess was to make the link shorter.
A tutorial gave me the information the original joomla htaccess will hide the /index.php/ in any links.
The link is too large to share it on the game the website is focused on.

Then I used RewriteRule ^streams/(.*)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R] to get rid of the category.

Sadly Im not able to write a htaccess file by my own.

So the link shoudlt work by using the menu and by entering the url into a browser.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, nonetheless a valid solution to your problem.

There are several extensions in the JED, try sh404, it will allow you to configure your SEF paths as you want them: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134

Comment: Great suggestion Riccardo - I have used sh404 in the past with great results for clients looking to do just as Robby is here.  While I believe it's possible using .htaccess (which I am not great at writing rules for); the extensions are another sure fire way to make it happen!